# VirtualBox и Linux - подгонка размера экрана гостевой ОС

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Имеется хост-машина с *Windows 7 x64*, на ней запущен *VirtualBox 5.0.12*, в котором развёрнута виртуальная машина *Linux Mint 17.3 x64*. В один прекрасный момент перестаёт подгоняться разрешение экрана гостевой ОС. Изменение разрешения экрана через GUI и `xrandr` работают, а автоматическое (при изменении размера окна или переходе в полноэкранный режим) - нет.

Что интересно - при растягивании окна на долю секунды дублируются обои, т.е. вроде бы как система пытается разрешение изменить, но оно тут же возвращается обратно.

Переустановка помогает ненадолго. В какой-то момент поведение опять портится. Версия дополнений роли не играет - на последней версии и на версии из репозитория (5.0.4) поведение идентичное. При загрузке с LiveDVD всё работает нормально. Виртуалка с *Windows 7* тоже работает нормально.

В чём может быть проблема и как её побороть?

---

***UPDATE 1***

Экспериментальным путём выяснилось, что автоподгонка разрешения перестаёт работать, если через GUI в свойствах дисплея выставить что-нибудь стандартное (1024x768, 1920x1080 и т.п.) и нажать <kbd>Apply</kbd>. Если сохранять нестандартное (типа 1854x812) - работает.

Изменения с помощью `xrandr` ничего не ломают.

---

***UPDATE 2***

Оказалось, что GUI создаёт файл

```
~/.config/monitors.xml
```

и записывает в него установленное разрешение экрана. Если этого файла нет или в нём разрешение, которое *что-то* считает некорректным, то всё работает. Но стоит прописать туда стандартное и тут же сбивается авторесайз.

Comment: Т.е. установка штатных пакетов virtualbox-guest-dkms, virtualbox-guest-x11 не помогает?

Comment: @donRumata Не помогает. Что со штатными, что с нештатными - поведение одинаково.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, изыскания привели к следующему результату.

Графический конфигуратор дисплея - апплет Дисплей/Monitor при сохранении настроек (нажатии Применить/Apply) создаёт файл

```
~/.config/monitors.xml
```

в который прописывается, в том числе, сохранённое разрешение экрана. При попытке изменения разрешения внешними средствами происходит перечитывание этого файла и возврат к установленным в нём значениям. Если этот файл удалить, изменение разрешения экрана гостевой ОС при изменении размеров окна виртуальной машины начинает работать корректно.

При перечитывании производится проверка сохранённого разрешения. Насколько я понял, для установки разрешения используется `xrandr`, который запрашивает у видеокарты список поддерживаемых режимов. Если режим есть в списке, `xrandr` меняет разрешение, если нет - ничего не делает. Поэтому при установке нестандартных разрешений всё работало - виртуальная видеокарта держит почти любое разрешение, но в ВМ выдаёт только небольшой их список.

Напрашивающееся решение проблемы - запретить создание или изменение файла `monitors.xml`. Как ни странно, смена владельца на `root` и установка "пустых" прав ни на что не повлияла - файл всё так же перезаписывался. Пришлось поступить более жестоко - создать пустой файл и выполнить команду

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

После этого файл перезаписываться перестал, но и апплет перестал изменять разрешение экрана, ругаясь на невозможность переименовать файл.

Впрочем, данное решение меня устроило. Теперь этот файл не мешает, случайно его изменить не удастся, а менять разрешение экрана ВМ можно при помощи самого VirtualBox'а - либо таская углы/стороны окна, либо при помощи меню:

```
Вид -> Виртуальный экран N -> Запросить разрешение в XxY
```

Изменённое таким образом разрешение при перезагрузке ВМ сохраняется, поскольку VBox хранит его в настройках ВМ.

---

Хотелось бы, конечно, заставить Linux игнорировать `monitors.xml` при смене размера окна, но мне этого сделать не удалось.